# Why ListView doesn't behave as expected when its height is set to wrap_content?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and for each view in its rows I have used the following layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_contactPhoto"
            android:tag="contact_photo"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription_contactPhoto" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_contactConversationSymbol"
            android:tag="contact_symbol"
            android:src="@drawable/they_said"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView_contactPhoto"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_contactPhoto"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription_contactPhoto" />
```

But I am only able to see the first image in each row, as if the second one doesn't exist at all. However, when I set the ListView's height to a specific value like:

```
    android:layout_height="192dp"
```

both images are there. any idea?

**EDIT**
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You can try to use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Check the documentation for RelativeLayout. You can't have alignParentBottom and wrap_content for height -- and it wouldn't make sense. Since you're setting the height and width of each element, why don't you just set a static height for it -- or better, follow the advice in the comment above and user LinearLayout, which does exactly what you aim to achieve.

Comment: Also, don't use fill_parent, use match_parent. (The former is deprecated). And check alecnash answer, you don't have to use "+" there, + is to create a new id, not to reference an existing one.

Comment: I removed the plus signs and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you really want to put the second image? If you want to put it above and left of the first one then you are doing something wrong. You have to delete the plus (+) sign in these two lines in your second ImageView so it looks like this:

```
        android:layout_above="@id/imageView_contactPhoto"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView_contactPhoto"
```

Comment: I did so, but the problem is still there. By the way, what's the point of the sign plus?

Comment: as Martín Marconcinipointed out "+ is to create a new id, not to reference an existing one"